# Why do I get errors while trying to execute a create statment using jdbc for neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

The statement is shown below modified almost directly from the neo4j java jdbc example.. I must be missing something

```
cypher.query("CREATE ({1}:{2} {name: '{3}'})", map("1",nameshort,"2",type,"3",name));
```

Comment: Well, since you haven't told us what the error is it might be difficult for anybody to answer unless the answer is EXTREMELY obvious.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to understand the requirements for posting here.

Comment: Please add the link of the tutorial you have followed and the errors you get !

Comment: As the other commenters have pointed out, please always include the error if you want someone to help. Luckily this time, it was quite obvious

Comment: thanks guys. Also, sorry for not giving enough information, but good news @Luanne got me. Even better news, after looking over the docs I found a better way to go about this. but again thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers and labels cannot be [parameterized](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html). {1} and {2} are therefore illegal, you need to specify them for example, like this-

```
CREATE (p:Person {name: {3}})
```

Don't quote the String parameter either.